# Show that each of the following equations has a solution of the form $u(x,y) = f(ax+by) $ for a proper choice of constant $a,b$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the constant for each example.

(a) $u_x + 3u_y =0$

(b) $3u_x - 7u_y = 0$

(c) $2u_x + \pi u_y =0$

Comment: Just plug in the proposed solution and see if some constant $a$, $b$ work.

Comment: Like this? $u_x = a f'(ax+by)$ and $u_y = b f'(ax+by)$ 
if I substitute into (a) , I'll get 
$af' + 3bf' =0$ 
then?

Comment: Exactly. So, $a=-3b$ follows.

Comment: so.., any value of $a+3b = 0$ ? 
why?

Comment: wait..., 
so any value of $a$ and $b$ that satisfy $a+3b=0$ will make $f(ax+by)$ the solution of the equation, right?

Comment: so.., how to solve this? any hint?

Comment: @Clayton is wrong. As given, $f$ is a function of one variable. That is to say: $f = f(s)$. We write $u(x,y) = f(ax + by)$ so that by chain rule $u_x = a\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}s}(ax + by)$ etc. So what you did with the guidance of vonbrand and Berci is correct. I suggest you write it up completely and neatly and post that as an answer to your own question here!

Answer (score 1):

I believe one of the comments to your answer gave a brief version of the answer that I am about to present.  Here is a somewhat more detailed approach.

First I will present the solution to the more general equation
$$
\alpha u_x + \beta u_y = 0,
$$
which I interpret to mean
$$
\alpha \partial_x u(x,y) + \beta \partial_y u(x,y) = 0.
$$

The claim is that all solutions to this equation are of the form $u(x,y)=f(ax+by)=f(g(x,y))$ in which $g(x,y)=ax+by$ for an appropriate choice of $a$ and $b$.  This is equivalent to saying that we can choose $a$ and $b$ to satisfy the following equation.
$$
\alpha \partial_x f(g(x,y)) + \beta \partial_y f(g(x,y)) = 0.
$$
Using the [chain rule](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx), I calculate, with $t=g(x,y)$,
$$
\partial_x f(g(x,y)) = \partial_t f(t) \partial_x g(x,y) = a f'(ax+by),\\
\partial_y f(g(x,y)) = \partial_t f(t) \partial_y g(x,y) = b f'(ax+by).
$$
Plugging this into the given equation gives
$$
0 = \alpha u_x + \beta u_y = \alpha a f'(t) + \beta b f'(t) = (\alpha a +\beta b) f'(t)
$$
Hence we need to choose $a$ and $b$ such that $\alpha a + \beta b =0$.  Since this is one equation with two unknowns, we can solve it by fixing $b$ to an arbitrary value.  In this case, I choose $b=1$ so that the dependency on $y$ is maintained, but the equations simplify.  With $b=1$, we must choose $a$ to satisfy $\alpha a + \beta = 0$, or
$$
a = -\frac{\alpha}{\beta}.
$$
You can check that this solves the given equation.  To solve each of the given equations, plug in the appropriate values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

Show that each of the following equations has a solution of the form u(x, y) = f (ax +
by) for a proper choice of constants a, b. Find the constants for each example.
(a) ux + 3uy = 0.
(b) 3ux − 7uy = 0.
(c) 2ux + πuy = 0.
To show that each of the given equations has a solution of the form (u(x, y) = f(ax + by)) for some constants (a) and (b), we can use the method of characteristics.

The general form of a first-order linear partial differential equation is given by:

[
A(x, y)u_x + B(x, y)u_y = C(x, y)
]

where (A), (B), and (C) are functions of (x) and (y).

The characteristic equation for this type of PDE is given by:

[
\frac{dx}{A} = \frac{dy}{B} = \frac{du}{C}
]

Solving the characteristic equations will give us the family of characteristic curves along which the solution can be written in the form (u(x, y) = f(ax + by)).

Let's find the solutions for each of the given equations:

**(a) (u_x + 3u_y = 0)**

Here, (A = 1), (B = 3), and (C = 0).

The characteristic equations become:

[
\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{3} = \frac{du}{0}
]

From the first two equations, we have (dx = dy/3), which simplifies to (3dx = dy).

Integrating this, we get (3x - y = k_1), where (k_1) is a constant.

Now, we have:

[
\frac{du}{0} = 0 \implies du = 0 \implies u = k_2
]

where (k_2) is another constant.

Therefore, the general solution is (u(x, y) = k_2 = f(3x - y)).

So, for this equation, (a = 3) and (b = -1).

**(b) (3u_x - 7u_y = 0)**

Here, (A = 3), (B = -7), and (C = 0).

The characteristic equations become:

[
\frac{dx}{3} = \frac{dy}{-7} = \frac{du}{0}
]

From the first two equations, we have (7dx = -3dy), which simplifies to (7dx + 3dy = 0).

Integrating this, we get (7x + 3y = k_1), where (k_1) is a constant.

Now, we have:

[
\frac{du}{0} = 0 \implies du = 0 \implies u = k_2
]

where (k_2) is another constant.

Therefore, the general solution is (u(x, y) = k_2 = f(7x + 3y)).

So, for this equation, (a = 7) and (b = 3).

**(c) (2u_x + \pi u_y = 0)**

Here, (A = 2), (B = \pi), and (C = 0).

The characteristic equations become:

[
\frac{dx}{2} = \frac{dy}{\pi} = \frac{du}{0}
]

From the first two equations, we have (2dx = \pi dy), which simplifies to (2dx - \pi dy = 0).

Integrating this, we get (2x - \pi y = k_1), where (k_1) is a constant.

Now, we have:

[
\frac{du}{0} = 0 \implies du = 0 \implies u = k_2
]

where (k_2) is another constant.

Therefore, the general solution is (u(x, y) = k_2 = f(2x - \pi y)).

So, for this equation, (a = 2) and (b = -\pi).

In conclusion, each of the given equations has a solution of the form (u(x, y) = f(ax + by)) with the specified constants (a) and (b) as shown above.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).